# Can Google gcloud DNS work with seconday DNS servers?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

We use Google Cloud DNS for primary DNS zone hosting. As a primary service is seems very functional. However, I cannot see how to allow zone transfers to a list of secondary DNS servers. This would be useful to provide further resilience. For instance, in Europe RIPE will act as a secondary on all delegated reverse DNS zones.

I have searched the web and the Google help for this information but I have not been able to find an answer. are secondary servers supported by Google Cloud DNS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is currently not supported.